# Is there an R function that can find multiple values per group?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, group-by, grouping

I have 3 groups in my dataset: Coffee, Tea, and Water. The dataset is as follows

```
df <- data.frame(drink = c('Coffee','Coffee', 'Coffee', 'Coffee', 'Coffee', 'Tea', 'Tea', 'Tea', 'Tea', 'Tea', 'Water', 'Water', 'Water','Water', 'Water'), date = as.Date(c('2020-08-01', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06', '2020-08-07')))
```

Now I have three types of drinks and the dates I drank each drink. Some days, I drank all three, some days two out of three, and some days just one out of three.

```
drink     date

Coffee    2020-08-01
Coffee    2020-08-02
Coffee    2020-08-03
Coffee    2020-08-04
Coffee    2020-08-05
Tea       2020-08-02
Tea       2020-08-03
Tea       2020-08-04
Tea       2020-08-05
Tea       2020-08-06
Water     2020-08-03
Water     2020-08-04
Water     2020-08-05
Water     2020-08-06
Water     2020-08-07
```

Lets say I want to know if there was any particular group where I drank on 08-04-2020, 08-05-2020 and 08-06-2020. I want to have a function that would return to me **tea and water** as I drank both of these on the days specified.

I was trying to use something like this but it is not working

```
with(df, drink[date == 2020-08-04 && date == 2020-08-05 && date == 2020-08-06])
```

Is there some other function that is able to look at the same group with different values in each row of that group and filter to check for values wanted? Maybe there is a way to use groupby. Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: Fixed it! Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function :

```
get_common_drink <- function(data, dates) {
  df1 <- subset(data, date %in% dates)
  Reduce(intersect, split(df1$drink, df1$date))
}

get_common_drink(df,  as.Date(c('2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06')))
#[1] "Tea"   "Water"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unstack` on `df` and subset it for the specific dates, and then use `intersect` within `Reduce` to find values in all subsets.

```
Reduce(intersect, unstack(df)[c("2020-08-04", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-06")])
#[1] "Tea"   "Water"
```

or subset before `unstack`

```
Reduce(intersect, unstack(df[df$date %in% as.Date(c("2020-08-04",
 "2020-08-05", "2020-08-06")),]))
#[1] "Tea"   "Water"
```